# Maximum help text characters on visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I know that field level help text is allowed to 255 characters.

But I would like to know what is the limit on the visualforce page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a particular limit specified. If anything you might hit usability limit (text too long to be read by users in full) or maybe viewstate/heap size/max VF page source size/max generated HTML size...

See this question on Salesforce StackExchange: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/need-help-text-of-more-than-255-characters

Standard "Lorem ipsum" text has 445 characters and that sample page I've made saved without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

By using "helpText" attribute on the "" tag, you can show field level help text for your fields on the visualforce page as your wish. Because, this attribute supports more than 5000 characters.